# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los datos perduren en una estructura de datos LIFO?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito que cada que ejecute mi programa los datos que en un momento fueron ingresados, se queden guardados y que no se pierdan cuando vuelva a ejecutar mi programa. Existe una forma de hacerlo?, que no sean bases de datos?.

```
import queue

new_user = queue.LifoQueue()
class Save_Users:
    def __init__(self, will_save_user):
        new_user.put(will_save_user)
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Entiendo que tendrás que guardar los datos en algún lado, por lo que podrías usar un `json`

Comment: Mira el módulo `pickle` para guardar datos python en un formato binario específico de python (que puede ser fácilmente recuperado por otro script python o por él mismo la próxima vez que se ejecute).

Comment: La opción de @abulafia es más que correcta. Lo único a tener en cuenta es el tamaño máximo de archivo (2Gb)